# Draw a polygon around point in scattermapbox using python

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash, mapbox-gl-js

I am using [plotlys scattermapbox](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/) to plot points on a map. I'd like to draw the polygon that cover `'x' mile` radius from a POI.

```
dcc.Graph(id="map-graph"),

@application.callback([

                         Output("map-graph", "figure"),
                      
                      ],
                      [

                         Input("address", "value"),
                         Input("type", "value")
                      ]
                      
                     )
def update_graph(address, type):
    
    for i, row in df.iterrows():

        lat = row["Lat"]
        lng = row["Long"]

        data.append({

                     "type": "scattermapbox",
                     "lat": [lat],
                     "lon": [lng],
                     "name": "Location",
                     "showlegend": False,
                     "hoverinfo": "text",
                     "mode": "markers",
                     "marker": {
                                "symbol": "circle",
                                "size": 8,
                                "opacity": 0.8,
                                "color": "black"
                               }
                      }
        )

     # Plot POI 
     POI_Lat = 37.785908
     POI_Long = -122.400803

     data.append({
                    "type": "scattermapbox",
                    "lat": [POI_Lat],
                    "lon": [POI_Long],
                     "marker": {
                        "symbol": "circle,
                        "size": 28,
                        "opacity": 0.7,
                        "color": "rgb(128, 128, 128)"
                        }
                    }
        )
```

`df` is a pandas dataframe that includes coordinates for locations within `x miles` of POI. How do I update the `map-graph` to draw a polygon that covers all the points?

Adding a layer to layout dictionary:

```
gdf = circles(Lat, Long, radius=1609.34)

print(gdf['geometry'][0])

POLYGON ((385272.0167249573 3768678.19769511, 385264.2673129799 3768520.454790493,.......))


layout = {

                        "autosize": True,
                        "hovermode": "closest",
                        "mapbox": {

                            "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                            "bearing": 0,
                            "center": {
                                "lat": layout_lat,
                                "lon": layout_lon
                            },
                            "layers": [
                                         {
                                             "source": json.loads(gdf.geometry.to_json()),
                                             "below": "traces",
                                             "type": "line",
                                             "color": "purple",
                                             "line": {"width": 1.5},
                                         }
                            ],
                            "pitch": 0,
                            "zoom": zoom,
                            "style": "outdoors",

                        },

                        "margin": {
                           "r": 0,
                           "t": 0,
                           "l": 0,
                           "b": 0,
                           "pad": 0
                       }

           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- based on answer to this duplicate question [Obtain coordinates of a Polygon / Multi-polygon around a point in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960541/obtain-coordinates-of-a-polygon-multi-polygon-around-a-point-in-python/68963478#68963478)
- no sample data provided in question,  so I've used UK hospital data
- have created a helper function `poi_poly()`. NB radius is in meters as per UTM geometry
- UTM geometry is used to create a polygon of specified radius
- markers are then intersected with this polygon. Then get the [convex hull](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.convex_hull.html)
- have provided option to return radius polygon as well, in example below I've returned this to demonstrate that the convex hull polygon is within the radius of the POI

```
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests, io, json
import plotly.express as px
import random


def poi_poly(
    df,
    radius=10 ** 5,
    poi={"Longitude": 0.06665166467428207, "Latitude": 51.19034957885742},
    lon_col="Longitude",
    lat_col="Latitude",
    include_radius_poly=False,
):

    # generate a geopandas data frame of the POI
    gdfpoi = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(poi["Longitude"], poi["Latitude"])],
        crs="EPSG:4326",
    )
    # extend point to radius defined (a polygon).  Use UTM so that distances work, then back to WSG84
    gdfpoi = (
        gdfpoi.to_crs(gdfpoi.estimate_utm_crs())
        .geometry.buffer(radius)
        .to_crs("EPSG:4326")
    )

    # create a geopandas data frame of all the points / markers
    if not df is None:
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=df.loc[:, ["Longitude", "Latitude"]]
            .dropna()
            .apply(
                lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Longitude"], r["Latitude"]), axis=1
            )
            .values,
            crs="EPSG:4326",
        )
    else:
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi)

    # create a polygon around the edges of the markers that are within POI polygon
    return pd.concat(
        [
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(
                geometry=[
                    gpd.sjoin(
                        gdf, gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi), how="inner"
                    ).unary_union.convex_hull
                ]
            ),
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi if include_radius_poly else None),
        ]
    )


# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that can be scattered
dfhos = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text
    ),
    sep="¬",
    engine="python",
)


# generate polygon of markers within 5 mile radius of Point of Interest
poi = dfhos.loc[random.randint(0, len(dfhos) - 1), ["Longitude", "Latitude"]].to_dict()
gdf = poi_poly(dfhos, poi=poi, radius=1609.34 * 5, include_radius_poly=True)

fig = (
    px.scatter_mapbox(
        dfhos,
        lat="Latitude",
        lon="Longitude",
        color="Sector",
        hover_data=["OrganisationName", "Postcode"],
    )
    .update_traces(marker={"size": 10})
    .update_layout(
        mapbox={
            "style": "open-street-map",
            "zoom": 9,
            "center": {"lat": poi["Latitude"], "lon": poi["Longitude"]},
            "layers": [
                {
                    "source": json.loads(gdf.geometry.to_json()),
                    "below": "traces",
                    "type": "line",
                    "color": "purple",
                    "line": {"width": 1.5},
                }
            ],
        },
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

#### draw just a circle polygon

- `poi_poly()` has been updated. DataFrame is no longer mandatory for finding markers within POI
- simple example of creating a circle (actually a polygon) centred on a single set of GPS co-ordinates

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

poi = {"Latitude": 37.785908, "Longitude": -122.400803}

go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox()).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "open-street-map",
        "zoom": 9,
        "center": {"lat": poi["Latitude"], "lon": poi["Longitude"]},
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": json.loads(poi_poly(None, poi=poi, radius=1609).to_json()),
                "below": "traces",
                "type": "line",
                "color": "purple",
                "line": {"width": 1.5},
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

[image]

Comment: I implemented your answer and added `layer` property to `layout` dictionary, however, the polygon circle isn't rendered. Question is updated with the code.

Comment: looking at the output of `print(gdf['geometry'][0])` the coordinates are not WSG84,  they look like easting / northing .  provide a sample of your df `df.head(20).to_dict("list")` or put on GitHub where I can access it

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/kevalshah90/draw_circles_polygons/blob/main/circles.py

Comment: I have a single poi at a time, so I am passing (Lat, Long).

Comment: my original understanding - you wanted a polygon of markers within a defined radius of a POI.  Have further increased utility of `poi_poly()` such that it will create a circle and not bother with additional logic of constructing a polygon of markers within the defined radius

Comment: still seems to be some issue with the polygon coords. can you check this file: https://github.com/kevalshah90/polygon/blob/main/layout.txt , I am printing the `geodataframe` and the layout object with `layers` property.

Comment: GitHub file,  not clear what it is.  when you run the same code that I've provided does it plot the circle somewhere else?  i..e. not SF

Comment: I don't see it the circle anywhere. I updated the GitHub file, can you check? It includes the geometry / polygon when I print `gdf` and the layout object which includes the function call.

Comment: I have added the `poly_poi` function as well to the github link.

Comment: have you just run the sample code I have provided?  I don't think so -  your partial code on GitHub is different as you are using a different mapbox style. also it's quite weird why is file extension .txt not .py.  I am really very lost to what you want to do,  what you have tried

Comment: I have changed the file ext to `.py`. I am using the `poly_poi` function you shared, but the layout was something that I already had in my code. Basically, I need a circle that encompasses all pois within `x mile` radius of a point. I'll add complete code into the file, so you can see what I have tried.

Comment: you are making multiple coding errors.  `poi_poly()` works with geocode lookup of **151 3rd St, San Francisco** have used https://pypi.org/project/geopy/ as I am not going to pay for google for SO.  paid consulting would be different.  coding errors: 1. `"textposition": "top right",  # ***** top-right !!! ****`. 2. the way you are appending **dict** is completely wrong,  coding not plotly.   not enough space to paste that here.   3. you make use of globals in `map_graph()` which is bad practice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236700/discussion-between-kms-and-rob-raymond).

Comment: I have updated the the code for appending to `dict` object. `layout["layers"] = {....}`. Also, fyi, have created a room for us to chat.

Answer (score 1):

See an example in the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-on-mapbox/)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers",
    lon = [-73.605], lat = [45.51],
    marker = {'size': 20, 'color': ["cyan"]}))

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': { 'lon': -73.6, 'lat': 45.5},
        'zoom': 12, 'layers': [{
            'source': {
                'type': "FeatureCollection",
                'features': [{
                    'type': "Feature",
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': "MultiPolygon",
                        'coordinates': [[[
                            [-73.606352888, 45.507489991], [-73.606133883, 45.50687600],
                            [-73.605905904, 45.506773980], [-73.603533905, 45.505698946],
                            [-73.602475870, 45.506856969], [-73.600031904, 45.505696003],
                            [-73.599379992, 45.505389066], [-73.599119902, 45.505632008],
                            [-73.598896977, 45.505514039], [-73.598783894, 45.505617001],
                            [-73.591308727, 45.516246185], [-73.591380782, 45.516280145],
                            [-73.596778656, 45.518690062], [-73.602796770, 45.521348046],
                            [-73.612239983, 45.525564037], [-73.612422919, 45.525642061],
                            [-73.617229085, 45.527751983], [-73.617279234, 45.527774160],
                            [-73.617304713, 45.527741334], [-73.617492052, 45.527498362],
                            [-73.617533258, 45.527512253], [-73.618074188, 45.526759105],
                            [-73.618271651, 45.526500673], [-73.618446320, 45.526287943],
                            [-73.618968507, 45.525698560], [-73.619388002, 45.525216750],
                            [-73.619532966, 45.525064183], [-73.619686662, 45.524889290],
                            [-73.619787038, 45.524770086], [-73.619925742, 45.524584939],
                            [-73.619954486, 45.524557690], [-73.620122362, 45.524377961],
                            [-73.620201713, 45.524298907], [-73.620775593, 45.523650879]
                        ]]]
                    }
                }]
            },
            'type': "fill", 'below': "traces", 'color': "royalblue"}]},
    margin = {'l':0, 'r':0, 'b':0, 't':0})

fig.show()
```

[image: polygon and point]
Adjust the above based on your point and polygon coordinates.

If you want to use another mapbox `style`:

> The accepted values for layout.mapbox.style are one of:
> "white-bg" yields an empty white canvas which results in no external HTTP requests
> "open-street-map", "carto-positron", "carto-darkmatter", "stamen-terrain",
> "stamen-toner" or "stamen-watercolor" yield maps composed of raster tiles from various public tile servers which do not require signups or access tokens
> "basic", "streets", "outdoors", "light", "dark", "satellite", or "satellite-streets" yield maps composed of vector tiles from the Mapbox service, and do require a Mapbox Access Token or an on-premise Mapbox installation.
> A Mapbox service style URL, which requires a Mapbox Access Token or an on-premise Mapbox installation.
> A Mapbox Style object as defined at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/

https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/

Comment: Is there a way to natively obtain the geometry of area within `x miles`  of the center using mapbox? I am referring to the coordinates of MultiPolygon geometry.

Comment: The coordinates for geometry are not fixed, in my case. I cannot hard code them in. I need to get the coordinates that represent the geometry around the POI / Center.

Comment: I've provided an example with hardcoded data, because I don't know what your data looks like. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? It's difficult to help without more details.